# how to import custom taxonomy (& terms)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, import, export

I exported a working Wordpress (v3.5.1) blog content with multiple custom taxonomies (& terms) and whenever I try to import these terms and taxonomy into a new blog the wordpress-importer fails with the message "failed to import ".

How can I 1) export and import custom taxonomies? (or) 2) fix the current export & import functions to make it work? ... looks like the terms are not created at all, even less associated to the posts.

thanks.

feel free to try it with the following export, where the post "hello world!" is associated with terms "parent term2" and "child term 1" of my custom taxony "taxonomy test": https://www.box.com/s/c6n14zjz509u20wuynqr

Comment: Do you have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? If so, can you add that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that you need to set up the same Custom Taxonomies in your new blog. If your old one was registered as "my_custom_taxonomy", create the same in your new blog. Don't create any entries, then try your import again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't export or import custom taxonomies. For terms to be imported, custom taxonomy with the same name must be registered on new website also. I don't know what you used on the old website for that, but there are plugins for that.